# PrimeFaces uploader: how to mark this component as required?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

in my application, I have a form with multiple primefaces fileUploader in simple mode. These uploader components are dynamically generated, one for each row of a dataTable.
I'd like to mark them as required so I tried this:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="aform">
   <p:dialog id="dlgId">
    <p:dataTable var="foo" id="table"
        value="#{myBean.fooList}">
        <p:column>
           <p:fileUpload value="#{foo.file}" mode="simple" required="true"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" ajax="false"
        actionListener="#{myBean.listener}" update="dlgId">
    </p:commandButton>
  </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

The problem is that the form is correctly working if I upload all the files but the validation is not executed. The PrimeFaces version is 3.4.

Comment: Works fine for me on 3.4.2, provided that you've added `<p:messages>` somewhere or are reading server log for enqueued but undisplayed messages.

Comment: The problem is that the table is inside a dialog and the dialog get closed when I click the button. When I open again the dialgog the messages are shown. In the button definition I have also the command to update the dialog.

Comment: Why didn't you describe like that in your question? You didn't tell any word about `<p:dialog>` so, it's assumed that the problem is reproduceable with exactly the given code straight inside a completely blank `<h:body>` of a completely blank (with 100% default settings) JSF project.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed the messages before, so I thought the dialog was not important. I updated the question now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, you have actually this form inside a dialog which get closed/hidden after submit. You basically need to let the `visible` attribute of the dialog evaluate `true` when [the form inside the dialog is submitted](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIForm.html#isSubmitted%28%29) and [there's a validation error](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29).

You can achieve it as follows:

```
<p:dialog ... visible="#{dialogForm.submitted and facesContext.validationFailed}">
    <h:form binding="#{dialogForm}">
        ...
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the dialog should not go inside a form, instead the dialog should have its own form (because 1) the dialog may be implicitly relocated to the end of body by JS and 2) you don't want to submit/process all other inputs which are outside the dialog's view). So if the dialog is currently by itself inside a form with all other input controls, you should move it outside, e.g. to the very bottom of the body.